# Thread Safe(TS) e Non Thread Safe(NTS) - O que são, qual a diferença?

Tags: php, thread, download

Quando alguém vai fazer o download do PHP, tem essas 2 opções: `ts` e `nts`, assim como extensões da linguagem. Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- O que são **Thread Safe(TS)** e **Non Thread Safe(NTS)**?
- Existe alguma diferenças entre eles?
- Cada um é recomendado para que tipo de desenvolvimento

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Da documentação do PHP:

> Thread Safety significa que o binário pode trabalhar em um contexto de
>   servidor de vários segmentos, como o Apache 2 no Windows. Thread
>   Safety funciona através da criação de uma cópia de armazenamento local
>   em cada segmento, para que os dados não colidam com outro segmento.
>
> Então, o que eu escolho? Se você optar por executar o PHP como um
>   binário CGI, então você não vai precisar de thread safety, porque o
>   binário é chamado em cada solicitação. Para servidores web
>   multithreaded, como IIS5 e IIS6, você deve usar a versão encadeada(
>   threaded version) do PHP.

Então, ele realmente depende da maneira que você deseja usar o PHP:

Apache + LoadModule: thread-safe
Apache + FastCGI: Non-thread-safe
IIS: thread-safe
IIS + FastCGI: Non-thread-safe

O [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/install.windows) tem mais instruções bem interessantes.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204758/php-thread-safe-and-non-thread-safe-for-windows), [Fonte 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php), [Fonte 3 (Fora SO)](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/my_word/difference_between_php_thread_safe_and_non_thread_safe_binaries)

Comment: IIS usa versao NTS, pq so roda no modo FASTCGI

Comment: O que são os referidos "segmentos"?