# Erro: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou usando o Apache para fazer um site localhost, porem tenho um banco online e queria acessar ele

Eu faço a conexão em php

```
<?php           
    $servername = "host.com";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "banco";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

Porem quando vou no site ele me retorna a a seguinte mensagem

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pasta\index.php:133 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pasta\index.php on line 133

Tentei editar o "php.ini-development" e php.ini-production na pasta do PHP colocando `extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"` mas não funcionou

Comment: Qual a versão do PHP?

Comment: Descomentou a linha `extension=php_mysqli.dll`? reinicou o apache?

Comment: Sim, tirei o ; da frente nos 2 php.ini
`;On windows:`
`extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"`

Comment: Reiniciou (restart) o Xampp/Wamp/easyphp/apache após descomentar?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu fiz a instalação manual do Apache e PhP, não usei o Xampp pq eu não conseguia nem ligar o Apache por ele

Answer (score 1):

O `php.ini` do Apache geralmente é diferente do `php.ini` que veem no php, se você instalou manualmente o php e o apache você deve configurar no httpd.conf o parametro `PHPIniDir`, supondo que o seu php esteja na `C:`.

Se for PHP5:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php/php.ini"
```

Se for PHP7:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php/php.ini"
```

> Creio que geralmente as dlls `php5apache2_4.dll` e `php7apache2_4.dll` veem na versão TS do PHP, creio que na NTS não contenha, mas não tenho certeza (irei revisar esta informação).
>
> Leia mais sobre TS e NTS em [Thread Safe(TS) e Non Thread Safe(NTS) - O que são, qual a diferença?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130887/3635)

Sendo Apache para Windows com Apache2handler é necessário baixar o `PHP Thread Safe` no link: http://windows.php.net/download/, se já estiver com o php correto ignore este passo.

Se sabe o caminho que esta no `PHPIniDir "...."` então procure ele e edite as extensões tirando o `;` da frente da linha deve ficar semelhante a isto:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=php_memcache.dll
;extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Então depois disto é necessário reiniciar o Apache, se instalou manualmente vai depender do tipo de instalação.

Se não tiver painel de controle mas tiver instalado como serviço pode tentar o comando:

```
cd C:\Apache24\bin
httpd -k restart
```

Se não funcionar é porque não é um serviço, então talvez tenha instalado o Apache Service Monitor, pode reiniciar por ele:

[image: Apache Service Monitor]

Se nada der certo, então tente fazer logoff do windows, ou reiniciar o windows.

---

Para quem usa Xampp pode usar o proprio painel, clique em Stop ao lado de Apache e depois clique em Start:

[image: xampp]

Comment: Acho que o problema ta em reiniciar o Apache
Quando tento reiniciar ele, aparece essa msg.
`[Mon Aug 21 15:30:36.261743 2017] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4408:tid 440] (OS 2)O sistema nÒo pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.  : AH00436: No installed service named "Apache2.4".`

Comment: @Alguek é porque **NÃO** é um serviço, eu deixei bem claro na resposta: `Se não funcionar é porque não é um serviço, então talvez tenha instalado o Apache Service Monitor`, se ainda sim não der certo, apenas reinicie o Windows e teste novamente.

Comment: Realmente, eu tenho o Apache Service Monitor, porem diferente dessa imagem que você postou, ele não encontra nenhum serviço do apache

Comment: @Alguek como você inicia o apache na sua máquina?

Comment: C:\Apache24\bin e abro o httpd.exe
Nisso abre uma tela DOS que fica sempre preta e não consigo digitar nada, porem o servidor fica online

Comment: @Alguek fecha essa tela do DOS (cmd) e então execute novamente o `C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe` e então verifique se o mysqli esta funcionando. Não esqueça de conferir o PHPIniDir no httpd.conf.

Comment: em vez de `PHPIniDir "C:/php/php.ini"` coloquei  `'PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/php.ini-production"` e ALELUIAMENTE FUNCIONOU kkkk
Obrigado pela por tudo e por ter essa paciência toda

Comment: @Alguek é porque o `php.ini` esta mal configurado ou não existe.

Comment: Ele na verdade não existe porem veio assim quando baixei o PHP no proprio site, pelo oque eu vi eles tiraram o ini e colocaram 2 arquivos o `php.ini-development` e `php.ini-production`

Comment: Não existe porque você deve criar se baseando no `php.ini-development` ou `php.ini-production`. Só pra constar `php.ini-development` é para desenvolvimento e `php.ini-production` é um exemplo para quando publicar online. @Alguek

Comment: Ah, eu que tinha que editar um desses 2 e criar o php.ini? Putz
Não vi isso em nenhum lugar, sou bem iniciante nessas coisas tb.

Comment: @Alguek se a maquina que instalou o Apache+php é APENAS para desenvolver faça uma copia do `php.ini-development` e renomei a copia como php.ini, nesse php.ini habilitie o `extension=php_mysqli.dll`, então configure o phpinidir com php.ini, feche o CMD com o Apache e abra novamente. Pronto deve funcionar 100%.