# PHP + MySQL --- Salvar dados no BD

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou fazendo um cadastro simples utilizando MySQL(bd), PHP(vericações e conexão com bd) e HTML(página). Quando eu clico no meu botão para cadastrar (salvar dados no bd) ele me devolve o meu próprio código PHP. Sou novato com PHP e este é meu primeiro projeto ligando um banco de dados pelo código, então não sei se está certo.

Tudo o que quero é que os dados sejam salvos no BD quando o botão de Cadastrar é clicado.

---

**Imagem do meu site HTML**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Cadastro de clientes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="imgs/icone.png"  type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

</head>
    <input type="button" class="voltar" value="←"  onclick=" return BackToComMenu()">

<body class="teste">
    <center><div class="caixa">
    <center><img id="logo" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo da FullTime"></center>



    <main>
        <form action="php/cadastrar.php" method="POST" id="FormCadastro">

            <p>Cadastro de Clientes</p>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
              <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
              <input name="email" type="text"  placeholder="Email" onclick="return checarEmail()" >
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
                <input name="celular" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="11">
                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
              </div>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
              <input name="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)">
              <i class="fa fa-address-card   fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
            </div>


            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enviar" onclick="return cadastrar()">

            </div></center>

        </form>
    </main>

</body>
```

---

**MySQL**[image: BD]

---

**PHP**

Conexão com o BD:

```
<?php 
$conect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$conect) die ("<h1>Falha na conexão com o Banco de Dados!</h1>");
$db = mysql_select_db("bd.sql");
?>
```

---

Código PHP para cadastrar:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("php/servidor.php");

if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {
    if (!empty($_GET['nome']) || !empty($_GET['email']) || !empty($_GET['telefone']) || !empty($_GET['cpf'])){

        $nome=$_GET['nome'];
        $email=$_GET['email'];
        $telefone=$_GET['telefone'];
        $cpf=$_GET['cpf'];

        $comando="INSERT INTO clientes(nomecli, emailcli, telefone, cpfcli) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$cpf')";
        $enviar=mysqli_query($conn, $comando);
        if ($enviar) {
            $_SESSION['mensagem']="Cadastrado com Sucesso";
            header("location:index.html");
            exit;
        }

        else{
            $_SESSION['mensagem']="Erro ao cadastrar";
            header("location:cadastro.html");
            exit;
        }
    }

    else{
        $_SESSION['mensagem']="Algum dos campos ficou em branco";
        header("location:cadastro.html");
        exit;   
    }
}

else{
    header("location:index.html");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Encontrei a solução para o meu problema através do seguinte link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230804/erro-uncaught-error-class-mysqli-not-found/230862#230862

Answer (score 1):

Olha, o erro que eu vejo neste código é que você envia as informações pelo método POST na linha 19

```
<form action="php/cadastrar.php" method="POST" id="FormCadastro">
```

E as recebe pelo método GET (url) no cadastrar.php !
Recomendo (até por segurança), que envie e receba as informações via POST. O código ficaria assim

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("php/servidor.php");

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['nome']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['telefone']) || !empty($_POST['cpf'])){

        $nome=$_POST['nome'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
        $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];

        $comando="INSERT INTO clientes(nomecli, emailcli, telefone, cpfcli) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$cpf')";
        $enviar=mysqli_query($conn, $comando);
        if ($enviar) {
            $_SESSION['mensagem']="Cadastrado com Sucesso";
            header("location:index.html");
            exit;
        }

        else{
            $_SESSION['mensagem']="Erro ao cadastrar";
            header("location:cadastro.html");
            exit;
        }
    }

    else{
        $_SESSION['mensagem']="Algum dos campos ficou em branco";
        header("location:cadastro.html");
        exit;   
    }
}else{
    header("location:index.html");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente fui desatento, mas o navegador continua a me devolver o próprio código como resposta.

Comment: @JonatanRocha poderia enviar um print?

Comment: Olá @DanieldeAguiar, eu fiz outro post, pois este foi classificado como "fora de escopo", e lá eu consegui resolver meu problema !! O problema estava na pasta do php, no arquivo php.ini e em suas extensões para ser mais específico :D

Answer (score -2):

Boa Tarde !!
Você enviou o formulário pelo método POST e está recebendo no arquivo cadastrar.php pelo método GET.
Veja exemplo abaixo no W3School.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, fiz as devidas modificações e, ainda assim, o navegador continua a me devolver o código PHP como resposta.