# Não consigo criar a conexão com o banco no meu arquivo php

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando conectar com o banco mais só aparece esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\Exemplo-02.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\Exemplo-02.php(3):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Database...', 'usuario', 'senha') #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\Exemplo-02.php on line 3

Já baixei os drivers necessários para o php mas não adiantou. Segue o código (é só um código simples para testar se está conseguindo conectar)

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Database=db1;server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;ConnectionPooling=0","usuario", "senha"); 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(id, nome) VALUES(1,'Eddy')");

$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Seguem também os drivers utilizados:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86.dll
```

Serei muito grato se puderem me ajudar, já faz um tempo que estou tentando resolver isso.

Comment: Qual sua versão do PHP? 7.1? e você só precisa utilizar apenas um driver. x86 pra arquitetura de 32 bits e x64 pra 64 bits, também veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130889/45722 pra saber se você precisa do nts ou ts

Comment: O meu php é  7.1.

Comment: Você adicionou todos os drivers no `php.ini`?

Comment: Sim eu adicionei.

Comment: Qual a arquitetura do seu computador? 32 bits ou 64 bits?

Comment: é 64 ,so que eu ja coloquei apenas os drive de 64,tem que colocar na pasta ext ? e depois adicionar no php.ini, ja fiz isso e ainda da o mesmo erro de nao encontrar os drives

Comment: Sim, você adiciona ele na pasta `ext/`. Tente adicionar apenas: `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll`

Comment: caso não funcione, tente `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll`. Claro que eles precisam estar na pasta.

Comment: ainda nao funcionou .

Comment: Aqui vai o codigo com a parte la no php.ini

Comment: ;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;

--> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64 <--

extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo

Comment: Eu fiz o seguinte desinstalei o php e instalei o 7.2, agora vou ter que baixar outros drives ou esses servem?

Comment: Faz bastante tempo que eu não mexo com PHP, mas é bem provável que você não irá conseguir usar o SQL Server, pois a extensão é para a versão 7.1 e não tem para o 7.2 ainda. Caso encontre drivers do 7.2, tente utilizar eles.

Comment: Certo , Obrigado pela Ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema que você. Corrigir adicionando no *php.ini* as extensões, reiniciei o *WampServer* (estou usando este no lugar do *Xamp*) e funcionou corretamente.

Outra coisa que fiz foi deixar apenas as *dll* do *x64* pois não iria usar as do *x86*. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado.